# Entity Framework 5.0 (C#): Seed method only run if Update-Database is run twice

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, fluent

I have the following model:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public byte[] PasswordSalt { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Submission> Submissions { get; set; }
    public virtual List<PROMembership> PROMemberships { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public Guid? PasswordRetrievalToken { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [Display(Name = "Full name")]
    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            if ((FirstName != null && FirstName.Length > 0) || (LastName != null && LastName.Length > 0))
            {
                return (FirstName + " " + LastName).Trim();
            }
            else
            {
                return EmailAddress;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With the following fluent configuration class:

```
public class UserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public const int EmailAddressMinLength = 3;
    public const int EmailAddressMaxLength = 62;
    public const int FirstNameMaxLength = 50;
    public const int LastNameMaxLength = 50;
    public const int AddressMaxLength = 100;
    public const int ZipCodeMaxLength = 20;
    public const int CityMaxLength = 50;
    public const int CountryMaxLength = 50;
    public const int PhoneMaxLength = 50;
    public const int NotesMaxLength = 1000;

    public UserConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("Users");
        HasKey(u => u.UserId).Property(u => u.UserId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        Property(u => u.EmailAddress).IsRequired();
        Property(u => u.EmailAddress).HasMaxLength(EmailAddressMaxLength);
        Property(u => u.PasswordHash).IsRequired();
        Property(u => u.PasswordSalt).IsRequired();
        Property(u => u.FirstName).HasMaxLength(FirstNameMaxLength);
        Property(u => u.LastName).HasMaxLength(LastNameMaxLength);
        Property(u => u.Address).HasMaxLength(AddressMaxLength);
        Property(u => u.ZipCode).HasMaxLength(ZipCodeMaxLength);
        Property(u => u.City).HasMaxLength(CityMaxLength);
        Property(u => u.Country).HasMaxLength(CountryMaxLength);
        Property(u => u.Phone).HasMaxLength(PhoneMaxLength);
        Property(u => u.Notes).HasMaxLength(NotesMaxLength);
        Property(u => u.PasswordRetrievalToken).IsOptional(); // somehow the DB is generated with this field required if this is ommited
        HasMany(u => u.Roles).WithMany(r => r.Users).Map(m => { m.MapLeftKey("UserId"); m.MapRightKey("RoleId"); m.ToTable("UsersInRoles"); });
        HasMany(u => u.Jobs).WithMany(j => j.Composers).Map(m => { m.MapLeftKey("UserId"); m.MapRightKey("JobId"); m.ToTable("ComposersInJobs"); });
    }
}
```

And with this context configuration class:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<WebProject.DataAccess.WebProjectContext>
{
    private readonly bool _pendingMigrations;

    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
        var migrator = new DbMigrator(this);
        _pendingMigrations = migrator.GetPendingMigrations().Any();
    }

    protected override void Seed(WebProject.DataAccess.WebProjectContext context)
    {
        if (!_pendingMigrations)
            return;
        // imagine seeding code here
```

So far, so good. When I execute Update-Database, everything works as expected and the Database is created/updated correctly and in the end, the seed method in my Context-Configuration class is executed.

Now I had to add some fields to the model. Using Add-Migration Command:

```
public partial class AddClientRepresentation : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.Users", "MiddleName", c => c.String(maxLength: 50));
        AddColumn("dbo.Users", "Company", c => c.String(maxLength: 50));
        AddColumn("dbo.Users", "State", c => c.String(maxLength: 50));
        AddColumn("dbo.Users", "SecondaryPhone", c => c.String(maxLength: 50));
        AddColumn("dbo.Users", "SecondaryEmailAddress", c => c.String(maxLength: 62));
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropColumn("dbo.Users", "SecondaryEmailAddress");
        DropColumn("dbo.Users", "SecondaryPhone");
        DropColumn("dbo.Users", "State");
        DropColumn("dbo.Users", "Company");
        DropColumn("dbo.Users", "MiddleName");
    }
}
```

And so I have the following classes:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public byte[] PasswordSalt { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Submission> Submissions { get; set; }
    public virtual List<PROMembership> PROMemberships { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string SecondaryPhone { get; set; }
    public string SecondaryEmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public Guid? PasswordRetrievalToken { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [Display(Name = "Full name")]
    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            if ((FirstName != null && FirstName.Length > 0) || (LastName != null && LastName.Length > 0))
            {
                return (FirstName + " " + LastName).Trim();
            }
            else
            {
                return EmailAddress;
            }
        }
    }
}


public class UserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public const int EmailAddressMinLength = 3;
    public const int EmailAddressMaxLength = 62;
    public const int FirstNameMaxLength = 50;
    public const int MiddleNameMaxLength = 50;
    public const int LastNameMaxLength = 50;
    public const int CompanyMaxLength = 50;
    public const int AddressMaxLength = 100;
    public const int ZipCodeMaxLength = 20;
    public const int CityMaxLength = 50;
    public const int StateMaxLength = 50;
    public const int CountryMaxLength = 50;
    public const int PhoneMaxLength = 50;
    public const int NotesMaxLength = 1000;

    public UserConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("Users");
        HasKey(u => u.UserId).Property(u => u.UserId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        Property(u => u.EmailAddress).IsRequired();
        Property(u => u.EmailAddress).HasMaxLength(EmailAddressMaxLength);
        Property(u => u.PasswordHash).IsRequired();
        Property(u => u.PasswordSalt).IsRequired();
        Property(u => u.FirstName).HasMaxLength(FirstNameMaxLength);
        Property(u => u.MiddleName).HasMaxLength(MiddleNameMaxLength);
        Property(u => u.LastName).HasMaxLength(LastNameMaxLength);
        Property(u => u.Company).HasMaxLength(CompanyMaxLength);
        Property(u => u.Address).HasMaxLength(AddressMaxLength);
        Property(u => u.ZipCode).HasMaxLength(ZipCodeMaxLength);
        Property(u => u.City).HasMaxLength(CityMaxLength);
        Property(u => u.State).HasMaxLength(StateMaxLength);
        Property(u => u.Country).HasMaxLength(CountryMaxLength);
        Property(u => u.Phone).HasMaxLength(PhoneMaxLength);
        Property(u => u.SecondaryPhone).HasMaxLength(PhoneMaxLength);
        Property(u => u.SecondaryEmailAddress).HasMaxLength(EmailAddressMaxLength);
        Property(u => u.Notes).HasMaxLength(NotesMaxLength);
        Property(u => u.PasswordRetrievalToken).IsOptional(); // somehow the DB is generated with this field required if this is ommited
        HasMany(u => u.Roles).WithMany(r => r.Users).Map(m => { m.MapLeftKey("UserId"); m.MapRightKey("RoleId"); m.ToTable("UsersInRoles"); });
        HasMany(u => u.Jobs).WithMany(j => j.Composers).Map(m => { m.MapLeftKey("UserId"); m.MapRightKey("JobId"); m.ToTable("ComposersInJobs"); });
    }
}
```

When I NOW run Update-Database, the migrations run fine, but the Seed method is NOT executed (no matter whether I use -Force).
If I run the Update-Database command a second time, the seed method is executed, but returns immediately because there are no pending migrations.

I digged into it step by step and found out, that if I comment out all the new fields (MiddleName, Company, State, SecondaryPhone, SecondaryEmailAddress) in the EntityTypeConfiguration, the seed method is executed the first time I run the Update command without any problems.

Did anyone experience the same issue? What can be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this code is the culprit:

```
if (!_pendingMigrations)
    return;
```

which makes sense why it would only run the 2nd time since you don't have any pending migrations at that point.

Comment: As I used the "Add-Migration" command, to add the new fields, there should be a pending migration. And as I stated, it works if i comment out the new fields in the EntityTypeConfiguration...

Comment: At least, I added a "throw Exception();" at the beginning of the seed method because I didn't trust the output of Update-Database ("Running seed method."). I wanted to make sure that Seed() is really called / not called.